# magento checkout and allowing countries with no postcode + payment method paypal

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal, bug

Is there a fix for allowing countries no postcode and paypal?  Paypal seems to require a postcode.

The interface should disable PayPal instead of allowing this to occur.

> ERR (3): exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'PayPal NVP
>   gateway errors: The field Shipping Address Postal Code is required
>   (#10730: Shipping Address Postal Code Empty). Correlation ID:
>   d8d6bf1b1fb4f. Version: 94.0.' in
>   app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:1062

Comment: Wouldn´t it be enough to just send a '0' as the postcode to Paypal if there is no postcode entered. i know that Irish people do this as they don´t havea postcode

Answer (score 1):

As PayPal representatives say, the service allows sending "00000" instead of the post code.

Right in the Observer, you can check whether this applies to the countries like Ireland and then opt it to change with the same "00000" value.

UPD Magento allows you to make the postcode field optional. However, PayPal sets this field as the Required one. Hence, some errors can occur.

Comment: So do you confirm that this is a Magento bug ? As by default with PayPal Express enabled, if you try to checkout with a country with no postcode it will trigger the OP error.

Comment: It is a Magento/Paypal bug yes as the postal code is needed by Paypal. So I would say its more a Paypal issue than Magento. You can also see that when you simply google for Paypal + Ireland, as Irish people cannot create  a paypal account due to this.

Comment: I've updated the answer. @DigitalPianism